# Can an activity loose its intent extras?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

The app crashes in `setParametersFromIntent` which is called in `onCreate` of the activity. The method throws a custom `RumtimeException` if a specific intent extra is not set.

The crash is only reported rarely, I was not able to reproduce the bug.

I checked the code and there seems to be no possible route the activity could be started without the parameter being set.

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: intent extra not set
    at com.myapp.myapp.activities.MyActivity.setParametersFromIntent(MyActivity.java)
    at com.myapp.myapp.activities.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5442)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I read that upon recreation of an activity, the intent extras are also restored, so I rule that out as a possible cause.

Does the log give any hints about *how* the activity has been started?

The `android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate` also seems suspicious, as instrumentation should be disabled in the released app. Could this be someone trying to analyze and mess around with the activity, causing this exception?

Comment: You think you could post some of the code snippets on how you were putting the extras and receiving them? It might be easier to find out what is going on if we can replicate the bug

Comment: Will do. Just to clarify, I was not able to replicate the bug and it happens only rarely according to crash reports. Updated my question.

Comment: Gotcha, does seem like a peculiar bug too.

Comment: Could it be that someone is decompiling the app and starting the activity incorrectly without parameters set? In Firebase Crashlytics the devices are not flagged as rooted. However the Instrumentation line seems strange.

Comment: Could be that, the only instance I can think of is if they are somehow getting to the activity that receives extras without first attending the one which sets them. Your activity name is MyActivity which is quite generic, I just want to confirm that is not the landing activity on boot up?

Comment: The activity name is not the original one. Also I expect Proguard to obfuscate the name. It’s not the start activity.

Comment: Is the activity that's crashing listed in the manifest with `exported="true"` ?

Comment: `exported` is not defined for that activity. Activity has no intent filters, so `exported` defaults to `false`.